# A problem on real analysis in which from derivative you need to tell about function.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable.if $f'(x)\to l $ as $x\to\infty,$then show that $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to l $ as $x\to\infty$ .

i have no idea where to start.any hint please

Comment: Can you use L'Hopital's rule? Or must you prove it directly?

Comment: @Michael To use L'Hopital don't you need that $f(x)\to \pm\infty$  so that $\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Comment: Good point.  I guess you can break into cases with $l\neq 0$ and $l=0$. Or just prove directly. @Stef

Comment: @Stef No, you only need the denominator $\to \pm \infty.$

Comment: @Michael. Yes, breaking into cases is a good idea. It works

Comment: @Eklavya : My intuition for a direct proof is that $f(x) = f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)dt$, which grows approximately linearly in $x$, so $f(x) \approx C + lx$ for large $x$.

Comment: @Michael The problem with that is $f'$ need not be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @zhw : Good point.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital only requires the denominator $\to \pm \infty $ (just like its cousin Stolz-Cesaro), but if you don't know that, then note that if $a$ is large and fixed and $x > a,$ we have

$$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{f(a)}{x} + \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x} = \frac{f(a)}{x} + f'(c)\frac{x-a}{x}$$

by the MVT.

Comment: c is between a and x.now if i take limit x tends to infinity ,then how f'(c) goes to l.or how c goes to infinity??

Comment: You would choose $a$ such that $x>a$ implies $|f'(x) -l|< \epsilon.$ It follows that $|f'(c) -l|< \epsilon.$